# Can we set a single file as external in Subversion?

Tags: file, svn, svn-externals

Can we set a single file as external in Subversion?

Answer (score 24):

Yes, it's possible with svn 1.6. It's [documented](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.externals.html) in the nightly build version of the svn book.

But even though file externals are working, you should only do it with text files (for now) because binary files [won't work correctly](http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=3368) as file externals.

Comment: the issue with binary files (http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=3368) is fixed

Comment: still one should note, that external files can only be included from the same repository as the folder that holds the externals-definition

Comment: Janosch: that's not true. file-externals can come from any repository.

Comment: Stefan, according to the documentation to which you linked, Janosch is correct.  Quoting from the documentation: "File externals cannot refer to files from other repositories."  That's further confirmed by the error messages I get when I try to external files in another repo: `'http://my.repo.server/src/external_repo/file1.html' is not in repository 'http://my.repo.server/src/current_repo'`  Can you elaborate on how to get files from other repositories to be externals?

Comment: @Stefan Same here - does not seem to be possible from another repository in 1.6

Comment: @Peter just tried it with 1.8 and it is still a limitation. The definitive answer then is to external a directory instead and ignore the other files in there.

Comment: Any news about this? Is there a feature request for this, which i dont find?

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the first answer, SVN Externals are documented in [Chapter 3 of the SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.externals.html), and quite a few syntax examples are given there.

In addition, this note is given:

> "Because the svn:externals property has a multiline value, 
>   we strongly recommend that you use svn propedit 
>   instead of svn propset."

In my experience testing Tortoise SVN v1.9.6 and svn.exe v1.9.5, the results are as-documented.

- Bringing in an external **folder** with all its files works.
- Bringing in a **single** file from the **same repo** works.
- Bringing in a **single** file from a **different repo fails** and this limitation is documented in the SVN book.

This leads to a clumsy workaround.  If you control both repos, you can clone an individual file into its own folder in the source repo (by Externals of a single file WITHIN a repo), and then Externals it across repo borders into the target repo by bringing in its entire folder, which contains only a single file.

Docs for doing this with the Tortoise SVN client are [on tortoisesvn.net](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-externals.html).

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't find a good example about how to create a svn file external. So I am providing an example here so it can be useful for others.

The format is

```
svn propset svn:externals "<local file> <remote svn file>" <local dir>
```

For e.g. following command

```
svn propset svn:externals "my.cfg https://myserver/my/svn/location/my_sample_file.cfg.template" my_folder
```

will create the file https://myserver/my/svn/location/my_sample_file.cfg.template under `my_folder` as `my.cfg`. Here obviously, I assume you already have the folder `my_folder` under your current directory which is under svn.

Comment: Strange, the SVN docs claim file externals are not possible across repositories.

Comment: Nikita Bosik's answer blelow is preferred as it allows relative paths.

Answer (score 1):

For SVN 1.9.4 the syntax is like folder's one:

```
svn propset svn:externals <remote file> <local file>
```

E.g., this will create file `local.txt` in the current directory referencing to `file.txt`:

```
svn propset svn:externals ^/trunk/path/to/file.txt local.txt
```